# Convergence of $\frac{z^{n}}{n}$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I was trying to see whether or not $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n} = 0$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and I'm having difficulty. I know that we need to show that $\left | \frac{z^{n}}{n} \right| = \frac{|z|^{n}}{n} < \epsilon,$ but I'm having trouble constraining $|z|^{n}$. Any hints would help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z|\leqslant1$, then $0\leqslant\left|\frac{z^n}n\right|\leqslant\frac1n$ and so you can apply the squeeze theorem.

Otherwise, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|z|^n}n=\infty$.

Comment: What if the denom were $n^{2}$ or $n!$ instead?

Comment: Those are other questions. I suggest that you post them as such.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(n^a |z|^n)=a\ln(n)+n\ln(|z|)\sim n\ln(|z|)\quad$ because $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\to 0$.

We need $|z|<1\iff \ln(|z|)<0$ to get the expression $\to -\infty$ and $|z|^n\to 0$, and you can notice that the value of $a$ does not really matters (it can be positive or negative), the exponential is always prevailing over the polynomial factors.

If $a<0$ you can also add $|z|=1$ in the set of convergence.

For $n!$ this is different because the factorial has some $n^n$ growth, i.e $\quad n!\ge \left(\frac n3\right)^n$

Thus $\dfrac{|z|^n}{n!}\le \left(\frac{3|z|}{n}\right)^n\to 0$ for any value of $z$.

Comment: How do you know that $\left( \frac{3|z|}{n}\right) ^{n} \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: The inners of the parenthesis goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. And "$0^\infty=0$".